# How do I pre-fill text fields in a form with info from a database in a .jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I'm trying to create a form that updates an entry in a MySQL database. The table is a users table that contains various fields related to the user. I need this page to work as an update form that takes a username that is passed to it via the previous page and pre-fills the text fields with the existing data. It's a model one application that uses a presentation, transport, and data layer. The transport layer is User.java and the data layer (that interacts with the database) is UserDB.java.

Here's the code, everything is functional except the pre-filling.

UPDATE: I've edited to reflect the changes from the answers below, I also want to note that "UserDB.getUsers()" returns an ArrayList.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.util.ArrayList,beans.*,data.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%
//get parameters from the request
String userName = request.getParameter("userName");

ArrayList userList = UserDB.getUsers(userName);
    User user = userList.get(0);
%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" type="text/css" />
<title>User Admin</title>

</head>
<body>


<div id="main">
  <h1>Update  User</h1>
  <h3>User Info</h3>
  <hr>
    <div id="content">
    <form action="updateUser.jsp" method="get">
      <p>User Name<br>
        <input type="text" name="userName" size="20" value="<%=userName%>"/>
      </p>
      <p>Password<br>
        <input type="text" name="password" size="20" value="<%=user.getPassword()%>"/>
      </p>
      <p>First Name<br>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" size="20" value="<%=user.getFirstName()%>"/>
      </p>
      <p>Last Name<br>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" size="20" value="<%=user.getLastName()%>"/>
      </p>
      <p>Email Address<br>
       <input type="text" name="email" size="20" value="<%=user.getEmail()%>"/>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Commit Update">
      </p>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know I'm doing something wrong with the "user" object, but I'm overlooking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are passing the username as a string

```
<%
//get parameters from the request
String userName = request.getParameter("userName");

user = UserDB.getUsers("userName");
//it should be (with out the quotes
user = UserDB.getUsers(userName);

%>
```

Comment: That was one error, thanks! I'm still getting errors though: "An error occurred at line: 8 in the jsp file: /updateForm.jsp
user cannot be resolved to a variable" I was told that I need to define "user", I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: yes its like declaring a variable of type `User`...

you need to say 


`User user = UserDB.getUsers(userName);`

you also need to import the user class in the jsp (use <%@ page import=""%>

Comment: Thanks, I've updated it now giving me. `<%
 //get parameters from the request
 String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
  
 User user = UserDB.getUsers(userName);
%>` but it's still not working. I should've mentioned that `UserDB.getUsers` returns an ArrayList, and the error is "An error occurred at line: 9 in the jsp file: /updateForm.jsp
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<User> to User"

Comment: in that case declare a variable of type ArrayList instead of User in your Jsp... `ArrayList userList = UserDB.getUsers(userName);`

you can further process the arraylist as required.

Comment: I've added this, but I don't understand how to use it. How do I get what I need from the array down into the fields? (Note that I've updated the code in the question to reflect this change)

Comment: you can then say `<% User user = userList.get(0); %>`

remember to check if the array is not null & the array has atleast 1 element for you to proceed.

Comment: `User user = (User) userList.get(0); `

Answer (score 0):

The "username" should have the quotes removed.  Also, where are you declaring user's type?
ie.

User user = ....getUser..